# Python (2.7): Why is there a performance difference between the following 2 code snippets that implement the intersection of two dictionaries

Tags: python, performance, python-2.7

The following 2 code snippets (A & B) both return the intersection of 2 dictionaries.

Both of following 2 code  snippets should run in O(n) and output the same results.  However code snippet B which is pythonic, seems to run faster.  **These code snippets come from the Python Cookbook.**

Code Snippet A:

```
def simpleway():
    result = []
    for k in to500.keys():
          if evens.has_key(k):
                 result.append(k)
    return result
```

Code Snippet B:

```
def pythonicsimpleway():
    return [k for k in to500 if k in evens]
```

Some setup logic and the function used to time both functions =>

```
to500 = {}
for i in range(500): to500[i] = 1
evens = {}
for i in range(0,1000,2): evens[i] = 1

def timeo(fun, n=1000):
    def void(): pass
    start = time.clock()
    for i in range(n): void()
    stend = time.clock()
    overhead = stend - start
    start = time.clock()
    for i in range(n): fun()
    stend = time.clock()
    thetime = stend - start
    return fun.__name__, thetime - overhead
```

With Python 2.7.5 using a 2.3 Ghz Ivy Bridge Quad Core Processor (OS X 10.8.4)

I get

```
>>> timeo(simpleway)
('simpleway', 0.08928500000000028)
>>> timeo(pythonicsimpleway)
('pythonicsimpleway', 0.04579400000000078)
```

Comment: You changed quite a lot between the two. Also, use the `timeit` module to time things.

Comment: you could have times using `timeit myfunc()` if you are using ipython, for example

Comment: I used the example in the Python Cookbook.  That is why is used their timing function.

Answer (score 8):

They don't quite do the same thing; the first one does a lot more work:

- It looks up the `.has_key()` and `.append()` methods each time in the loop, and then calls them. This requires a stack push and pop for each call.
- It appends each new element to a list one by one. The Python list has to be grown dynamically to make room for these elements as you do so.

The list comprehension collects all generated elements in a C array before creating the python list object in *one* operation.

The two functions do produce the same result, one is just needlessly slower.

If you want to go into the nitty gritty details, take a look at the bytecode disassembly using the `dis` module:

```
>>> dis.dis(simpleway)
  2           0 BUILD_LIST               0
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (result)

  3           6 SETUP_LOOP              51 (to 60)
              9 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (to500)
             12 LOAD_ATTR                1 (keys)
             15 CALL_FUNCTION            0
             18 GET_ITER            
        >>   19 FOR_ITER                37 (to 59)
             22 STORE_FAST               1 (k)

  4          25 LOAD_GLOBAL              2 (evens)
             28 LOAD_ATTR                3 (has_key)
             31 LOAD_FAST                1 (k)
             34 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             37 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       19

  5          40 LOAD_FAST                0 (result)
             43 LOAD_ATTR                4 (append)
             46 LOAD_FAST                1 (k)
             49 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             52 POP_TOP             
             53 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           19
             56 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           19
        >>   59 POP_BLOCK           

  6     >>   60 LOAD_FAST                0 (result)
             63 RETURN_VALUE        
>>> dis.dis(pythonicsimpleway)
  2           0 BUILD_LIST               0
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (to500)
              6 GET_ITER            
        >>    7 FOR_ITER                24 (to 34)
             10 STORE_FAST               0 (k)
             13 LOAD_FAST                0 (k)
             16 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (evens)
             19 COMPARE_OP               6 (in)
             22 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE        7
             25 LOAD_FAST                0 (k)
             28 LIST_APPEND              2
             31 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            7
        >>   34 RETURN_VALUE
```

The number of bytecode instructions *per iteration* is much larger for the explicit for loop. The `simpleway` loop has to execute 11 instructions per iteration (if `.has_key()` is True), vs. 7 for the list comprehension, where the extra instructions mostly cover `LOAD_ATTR` and `CALL_FUNCTION`.

If you want to make the first version faster, replace `.has_key()` with an `in` test, loop directly over the dictionary and cache the `.append()` attribute in a local variable:

```
def simpleway_optimized():
    result = []
    append = result.append
    for k in to500:
        if k in evens:
            append(k)
    return result
```

Then use the `timeit` module to test timings properly (repeated runs, most accurate timer for your platform):

```
>>> timeit('f()', 'from __main__ import evens, to500, simpleway as f', number=10000)
1.1673870086669922
>>> timeit('f()', 'from __main__ import evens, to500, pythonicsimpleway as f', number=10000)
0.5441269874572754
>>> timeit('f()', 'from __main__ import evens, to500, simpleway_optimized as f', number=10000)
0.6551430225372314
```

Here `simpleway_optimized` is approaching the list comprehension method in speed, but the latter still can win by building the python list object in one step.

Comment: They both return the same results don't they? Is there a case where they would output different results for the same input?  I think your answer about why one is more efficient than the other is correct.

Comment: @ppone: They output the same result; the `.keys()` call in the `for` loop is redundant (and costs you time to call), and the `evens.has_key(k)` test is more efficiently executed as `k in evens`, but result is absolutely equivalent.

Comment: That's very interesting. It does not really explain it to me, since generating a C array is the main work here. Why would it take less time then appending one by one. What happens under the hood? Also I've done some tests with Python3.3 and I didn't see any differences. Did they change the implementation in it?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, everything is exactly the same, except that Python3 does not have `has_key` (using `in` instead).

Comment: @freakish: That is a *big* difference already. `in` is a simple comparison operation (one bytecode) versus an attribute lookup and a function call for `.has_key()`.

Comment: @freakish I just tested the code out in python 3.3.2 with 1 modification to simpleway function [if evens.has_key(k): => if k in evens].  They pythonicsimpleway is still faster, however simpleway has caught up in speed. ('pythonicsimpleway', 0.037243000000000026) vs ('simpleway', 0.049810999999999994).  It is now hard to compare since it is not the same function.

Comment: Wow, so `has_key` really is the culprit here (at least most of the performance is lost due to it). I'm shocked. I mean I would understand this kind of difference, but not 100%!

Comment: @freakish: The attribute lookup is partly to blame, you can remove that by caching the function in a local variable. But yes, function calls are expensive.

Comment: @MartijnPieters  def filterway():
...     return filter(evens.has_key, to500.keys()) is even faster than the pythonicsimpleway

Comment: @ppone: you can leave *off* the `.keys()`: `filter(evens.has_key, to500)` will do. That is a loop entirely in C, with a cached attribute lookup, which is why it is faster still.